# How to add two radial progress bars (JS) in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I'm trying to insert two identical radial progress bars in the same page but the code for the second one is ignored/invisible.
It's surely a JS issue so I'm here to ask your help.

JS Code:

```
 var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

 var options = {
percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 120,
lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 10,
rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
 }

 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var span = document.createElement('span3');
 span.textContent = options.percent + '%';

 if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
 }

 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

 el.appendChild(span);
 el.appendChild(canvas);

 ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
 ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

 //imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
 var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

 var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
    percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
    ctx.stroke();
 };

 drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
 drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
```

Each of the bars are called in the body using a container div with a unique id:

```
 <div id="graph"></div>
```

How can I use this code twice in the same page or / How can I display this progress bar twice?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple elements can not have the same ID. It needs to be a class if you intend to apply it to multiple elements. If you have the same ID on multiple elements, the selector will stop at the first one it finds.

Comment: Coudn't be used a new ID like graph2 for the second one? In this case what js codes should I change to make it work correctly?

Comment: You could use a different ID, yes. You would just have to do the whole thing twice, using the two different IDs. I think it would be simpler to just use a class, though